# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn displaying text string for values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I've been wrapping my head around this problem but am unable to solve this.
I have a datagrid that should display all settings in a database. Each setting belongs to a setting group which has a name and an Id but the foreign key for the group is the id.
In the grid itself should be a combobox for a column called **Group** which should contain the names of all the groups in the database but when you select a group it should put the group id to that setting not the name i.e display the name use the id.
I'm pretty new to xaml so I do not understand the bindings fully but here is what I've tried.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgSettings" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectionMode="Single"  SelectionUnit="Cell"  CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="20*"/>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="colGroupName" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding GroupId, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Group" Width="10*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" Width="30*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="20*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Header="Type" Width="10*"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Use}" Header="Use" Width="5*"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PendingRemoval}" Header="Delete" Width="5*"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
dgSettings.DataContext = null;
List<Setting> settings = service.GetSettings();
List<SettingGroup> groups = service.GetSettingGroups();
settingItems = new List<SettingItem>(settings.Count);
foreach (Setting setting in settings)
{
    SettingItem item = new SettingItem(setting);
    item.HasChanged = false;
    settingItems.Add(item);
}
List<string> groupNames = new List<string>(groups.Count);
foreach (SettingGroup grp in groups)
{
    groupNames.Add(grp.Name);
}
dgSettings.DataContext = settingItems;
colGroupName.ItemsSource = groupNames;
```

As you can see I put a string list of the group names as the ItemsSource for the combobox, this works, the combobox displays the list but the problem is setting the selected item for each item in the datagrid. How do I do this? Each item has a groupId but it has to be translated to the correct item in the combobox.

Solved!

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="colGroupName" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="GroupId" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding GroupId, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Hópur" Width="10*"/>
```

Comment: I believe you want to just
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource={"Binding Path=Groups,mode=twoway"} DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Group" Width="10*"/>